# Help with MVC 3 Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, routes

I have a simple route structure in my MVC 3 app that is breaking in an unexpected way.

My URL structure is fairly simple, but contains a handful of variables.

http://site.com/{location}/{stage}/{controller}/{action}/{id}

examples:

- http://site.com/ny/prod/server/list - list all prod servers in ny
- http://site.com/ny/test/server/123456 - list the details for the server in ny, in the test stage, with id 123456
- http://site.com/ny/prod/server/reboot/565656 - reboot the server in ny, in the prod stage, with id 565656

I created the following route in my Global.asax file.

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{location}/{stage}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller="server", action="list", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

This works fine for displaying a list of servers and the details of a server at /server/details/id, but when I try to execute a reboot, I get an error.

URL:  http://site.com/ny/prod/server/reboot/565656

> The view 'ny' or its master was not found or no view engine supports
>   the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ...

Why would it try to look for a view name ny.cshtml?

Comment: Not sure why it would try to find a view named ny.cshtml but you could take a look at it with Phil Haack's route debugger:  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: would you display your route map?

Comment: What does your Reboot() method look like? In addition, a useful route debugger is http://getGlimpse.com/

Comment: I have Glimpse installed via Nuget, but because I get an error, I can't view any of the debug info.

Comment: I prototyped what you have written and it worked fine.  As @Taesung Shin said what's the rest of your route map? And what is the Reboot method on the Server controller?

Comment: Check that your controller isn't passing in a string model in the `reboot` action to `View()` for instance, if you're doing `View(location)` it will cause the error your receiving.

Comment: Have you configured any other routes?

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is that you are either not using a constraint to define what location and stage should look like and it is giving you false positives and reading things in where they are not supposed to or you have your route definitions in the wrong order

make sure you have the default mvc defined last and if you have multiple custom routes constrain the either using a regex or custom constraint class to define what locations are valid and they should look like

eg http://site.com/ny/test/server/123456

- is ny a valid location - make a custom constraint that defines what a
  valid location is validate it against a database or a list of valid
  locations
- is test a valid stage - regex could be sufficient but i always try to avoid regex whenever possible as it is evil and hard to maintain. again i would write a custom constraint to define what stages are valid likely validating against a list is sufficient is the case as you shouldnt  have very many stages 
  also to be noted with using stages the way you are in your url you can also add authentication rules in a constraint so that for exaple only people that are ..say.. admin or stakeholder roles be mached to the route and regular or non authenticated users would simply fall through to the next route or can simply give a 404

writing routes can be tricky so it is advised to contrain your input data as much as you can especially if you are accepting string data

stephen walther has a good post on writing route constraint at his [blog](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx)